# How to scale one specific Rest API without microservice?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, microservices, threadpool, scaling

I am developing web application backend with Spring where client and server talk through Restful APIs. There is a specific API where I assume the hit will be much. Is there any way to scale this specific API?( Like, assigning more threads)
In this application everything is interdependent. So, microservice wont be best approach I guess.

Comment: I t will be almost impossible to help you without more infromation about the use-case

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways, i can think of

- Use Load Balancer, this will help you to add multiple application instances of Rest API. This is classical approach in such cases.
- This depends upon existing implementation, API can be refactor to just receive the message and decouple the processing thread.

The your suggested way of increasing thread has limitation and more fine tuning require. If the use case is just to support limited user, following configure can be use. [tomcat thread pool](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.tomcat.threads.max).

Answer (score 0):

Just have multiple instances of the same service. REST has a statelessness constraint, so it is easy to do it.